# Is it posible to make navMesh on an object while there's another navMesh in the scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

before I start a question, please understand if my English is weird.

Okay, so let's say you have a plane with navMesh baked on it. Is it posible to make another navMesh on an object? I want to make "object A" to move around the plane, and make "object B" to move around on the moving "object A".

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong (never had to do with NavMesh so far) so go ahead and correct me but I would say: **No.**

The [Manual -> NavMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html) states

> The process of creating a NavMesh from the level geometry is called NavMesh Baking. The process collects the Render Meshes and Terrains
> of all Game Objects which are marked as [**Navigation Static**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html), and then processes them to create a navigation mesh
> that approximates the walkable surfaces of the level.

A **static** GameObject, though, as the name suggests is **static**, meaning among other things: It doesn't move!

So as I understand it and if I'm not totally mislead I would say if your `objectA` is moving, then it is **not applicable** for a `NavMesh`.